# Developing ability: thinking in learning

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study

It says in [Tosafot Sotah 21a - *זה תלמוד חכם*](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Sotah.21a.13.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> סתם תלמיד חכם תורתו אומנתו, ועוסק בה ומהרהר כל שעה. ואינו הולך ד' אמות בלא תורה

Is there any detailed, practical guidance available about developing an ability to "think in learning" and its potential benefits?

UPDATE: Some asked for how this idea apparent from this quotation. I found this idea in sefer Alei Shur I., p. 70:

[image: Alei Shur I., p. 70]

Comment: This seems to be many different questions. You should split them up. The first one also seems to be opinion based, so you won't get any good answers.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it! I hope now it is better.

Comment: The Litvisher answer to this is probably that you should train yourself to think *bichlal*.

Comment: How do you get "think _in_ learning" (my emphasis) from the quote?

Comment: To clarify: You are asking for help spending time thinking about learning?

Comment: I am asking to be able to think about a sugya, while spending idle time, waiting for something, or walking on the street, or as in the famous, following story (although this would be an extreme example of this): https://www.bircas.org/parshas-yisro-5779/

Comment: When you are really interested in a sugya, it kind of happens naturally.

Answer (score 5):

The author of Bilvavi Mishkan Evne writes that, in order to make one's learning penetrate deeply, one should not be satisfied with learning a few hours a day, then continuing the next day, but should instead find one interesting problem/question during the day's learning, and think over it again and again all day long, during any free moment. This way one is always "engaged in learning" and the learning really penetrates.

I'm afraid he doesn't get more specific than this.

Comment: He probably means that if you have an interesting question, you will naturally think about it on your own.